# Ajax request in symfony no return

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, symfony

I have this template :

```
<div class="save-icon" style="margin-top: 2%">
   <a href="" onclick="changeNumber({{ number.getId }})">Link</a>
</div>
```

The js :

```
{% block javascript %}
{{ parent() }}
<script type="text/javascript">
    function changeNumber(id){
        console.log(id);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "{{path('numbers_update')}}",
            data: { id:id},
            success: function(msg){
                //alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
            }
        });
    }
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

In the source of page I have :

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function changeNumber(id){
        console.log(id);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/app_dev.php/admin/numbers/update",
            data: { id:id},
            success: function(msg){
                //alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

The config for `numbers_update` route :

```
numbers_update:
path: /numbers/update
defaults: { _controller: ClientBundle:Admin/NumbersBlock:update }
requirements:
    _method:  POST
```

The methode `updateAction()`

```
public function updateAction(Request $request){
    $i_id = $request->request->get('id');
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    return $this->json(array());
}
```

I use basic authentification, so I'm added this call in the `security.yml` :

```
access_control:
 - { path: ^/admin/homepage, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
 - { path: ^/admin/numbers, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
 - { path: ^/admin/numbers/update, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

I'm logged now but I don't get a retourn after ajax request.

Please help me ! I don't understand what can be the problem. Do you have some ideas ? ...Thx in advance.

Comment: What's the response code? Try to comment all lines in your action besides last one and check if the response code is 200

Comment: The same problem....Response is 200

Comment: Did you tried return JsonResponse()?

Comment: So everything seems to be ok. Try returning like this:

return new JsonResponse(['test' => 123]);

Comment: @RafałMnich the same problem...Very strange

Comment: The problem is that I don't have a response when I looked in the console of firefox

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a `return false` on one of two possible places in your handler.
Either do this:

```
 onclick="changeNumber({{ number.getId }}); return false;"
```

or

```
 onclick="return changeNumber({{ number.getId }});"
```

If you go with the 2nd solution - you'll need to add a `return false;` at the end of your `changeNumber` function.

The problem here is that, when you click on this `<a>`, the call to your handler actually works and it probably does the AJAX call, but you don't see it.
Since you are not preventing the default behavior of an `a.click`, the page actually follows the link given in the `href` (besides calling your handler) and you leave the current page (or possibly go again to same one).

Whether you go to different page or the same one, the WebDeveloper tool will most likely refresh and you won't see the AJAX call listed.

A tip for WebDeveloper tool: it may help to also enable the not-clearing of the Console and Network tabs between page submits and refreshes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to :

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
```

and

```
return new JsonResponse(array('key' => 'value' ));
//instead of 
return $this->json(array());
```

Clear cache to be sure.

In chrome, you can find more about the error in "network" tab in developper tools (when you use ajax).

Comment: Did you saw the symfony error page in network tab??? It is an 500 error??
You have to look this error page or you will not easily find your mistake...

Comment: when a ajax request is made, you will have a new line (or many) in the network tab of your browser.
Click on the line that is corresponding to your url (numbers/update), you will see the error page of symfony there (in dev mode of course).
Show us this error page

Comment: In the network tab, I have only : `http://www.daciacleaning.dev/app_dev.php/_wdt/1550c2`

Comment: when you are in the network tab, perform the ajax request

Comment: Don't understand really what happen

Comment: I don't see the request :`/app_dev.php/admin/numbers/update`

Comment: The page is reload after ajax call, I don't understand why

Comment: Reload is done because the onclick is not stopping propagation of event and anchor works. What you have to do is add return false alter method call like @userfuser said

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="" onclick="changeNumber({{ number.getId }})">Link</a>
```

I suggest you modify the href link, your href = "",
When you click on this page will refresh again. Even if you go away ajax. Because the refresh the page, you also look not to come out. You can instead
Href = "javascript:;" Elsewhere, and then you according to the normal way of thinking to write.